# Is it possible to use Haskell's type system (GADTs) to do some sort of polymorphic variants?

Tags: haskell, gadt

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}

module Action where

import Data.Type.Set

data Configuration
  = A
  | B
  | C

data Action (configuration :: Configuration) where
  Action1 :: Member cfg '[ 'A ]     => Action cfg
  Action2 :: Member cfg '[ 'B, 'C ] => Action cfg
  Action3 :: Member cfg '[ 'A, 'C ] => Action cfg

exhaustive :: Action 'A -> ()
exhaustive Action1 = ()
exhaustive Action3 = ()
```

I have a set of actions, and a set of configurations, but some actions only make sense in some configurations. I'd like to not have to explicitly discard irrelevant actions in a configuration, so I thought about using GADTs. Unfortunately, the type-checker is not able to realize that my `exhaustive` function is indeed exhaustive.

I wonder whether I can use any of the existing type-level lists/sets, or even row-types (as in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/row-types-0.2.3.0/docs/Data-Row-Variants.html ) to solve this problem.

I have also tried an approach where `Action2 :: Action '[ 'B, 'C ]` and pushing the type class constraints into `exhaustive`, to no success.

Thanks for any suggestions! (or even reasons why this is a bad idea, or not feasible easily)

Comment: If you aren't planning on having many actions, you could always just have `data Action (capabilityA :: 'Bool) (capabilityB :: 'Bool) (capabilityC :: 'Bool) where { ... }`. Then, `exhaustive :: ('True ~ capA) => Action capA capB capC -> ()` sort of works.

Comment: No, there will be possibly a hundred actions! :-(

Answer (score 3):

A friend suggested a solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

module Action where

type family MemberB (x :: k) (l :: [k]) where
  MemberB x '[]     = 'False
  MemberB x (x:xs)  = 'True
  MemberB x (x':xs) = MemberB x xs

type Member x xs = MemberB x xs ~ 'True

data Configuration
  = A
  | B
  | C

data Action (configuration :: Configuration) where
  Action1 :: Member cfg '[ 'A ]     => Action cfg
  Action2 :: Member cfg '[ 'B, 'C ] => Action cfg
  Action3 :: Member cfg '[ 'A, 'C ] => Action cfg

exhaustive :: Action 'A -> ()
exhaustive Action1 = ()
exhaustive Action3 = ()
exhaustive Action2 = ()
```

Apparently, the problem is that the `Member` I was using (from `Data.Type.Set`) was not a **closed** type family.  Now, the error messages aren't great, and we tried to do the following:

```
type family MemberB (x :: k) (l :: [k]) where
  MemberB x '[]     = TypeError ('Text "not a member")
  MemberB x (x:xs)  = 'True
  MemberB x (x':xs) = MemberB x xs
```

But unfortunately, this eats the type error! Is it because `TypeError` will happily unify with `'True`? If anyone has a solution to make the type error slightly nicer, I'd happily take it!

I made a separate question for this:

[How to define a custom type error within a type family for a constraint that uses type equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52730463/how-to-define-a-custom-type-error-within-a-type-family-for-a-constraint-that-use)