# How to define a custom type error within a type family for a constraint that uses type equality?

Tags: haskell, type-constraints, type-families

So, one can define a membership constraint like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Whatever where

type family MemberB (x :: k) (l :: [k]) where
  MemberB _ '[]      = 'False
  MemberB a (a : xs) = 'True
  MemberB a (b : xs) = MemberB a xs

type Member x xs = MemberB x xs ~ 'True

data Configuration = A | B | C

data Action (configuration :: Configuration) where
  Action1 :: Member cfg '[ 'A ]     => Action cfg
  Action2 :: Member cfg '[ 'B, 'C ] => Action cfg
  Action3 :: Member cfg '[ 'A, 'C ] => Action cfg

exhaustive :: Action 'A -> ()
exhaustive Action1 = ()
exhaustive Action3 = ()
exhaustive Action2 = ()
```

But the error message we get is not very informative:

```
 • Couldn't match type ‘'False’ with ‘'True’
   Inaccessible code in
     a pattern with constructor:
       Action2 :: forall (cfg :: Configuration).
                  Member cfg '['B, 'C] =>
                  Action cfg,
     in an equation for ‘exhaustive’
 • In the pattern: Action2
   In an equation for ‘exhaustive’: exhaustive Action2 = () (intero)
```

It'd be nice to use the new `TypeError` feature to improve on this message, however, a naive solution gobbles the error:

```
import GHC.TypeLits

type family MemberB (x :: k) (l :: [k]) where
  MemberB _ '[]      = TypeError ('Text "not a member")
  MemberB a (a : xs) = 'True
  MemberB a (b : xs) = MemberB a xs
```

It seems that, maybe, `TypeError` behaves as any type, and so it unifies happily with `'True`?

Is there a way to get a nice type error, while preserving the membership behavior?

Comment: I do get the error: `29:7: error:
    • not a member
    • In the expression: foo
      In an equation for ‘bar’: bar = foo
`

Comment: Wow, maybe I should update my GHC!? Let me check!

Comment: Ha, I had over-simplified the problem, updating it now...

Comment: @dfeuer ha, I updated the code but not the error message, fixed now

Answer (score 4):

Well, it doesn't use `TypeError`, but you might find it interesting anyway:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Whatever where

data IsMember k = IsMember | Isn'tMember k [k]

type family MemberB (x :: k) (l :: [k]) (orig :: [k]) where
  MemberB a '[]      ys = 'Isn'tMember a ys
  MemberB a (a : xs) ys = 'IsMember
  MemberB a (b : xs) ys = MemberB a xs ys

type Member x xs = MemberB x xs xs ~ 'IsMember

data Configuration = A | B | C

data Action (configuration :: Configuration) where
  Action1 :: Member cfg '[ 'A ]     => Action cfg
  Action2 :: Member cfg '[ 'B, 'C ] => Action cfg
  Action3 :: Member cfg '[ 'A, 'C ] => Action cfg

exhaustive :: Action 'A -> ()
exhaustive Action1 = ()
exhaustive Action3 = ()
exhaustive Action2 = ()
```

The error is a bit more informative now:

```
test.hs:32:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘'Isn'tMember 'A '['B, 'C]’ with ‘'IsMember’
      Inaccessible code in
        a pattern with constructor:
          Action2 :: forall (cfg :: Configuration).
                     Member cfg '['B, 'C] =>
                     Action cfg,
        in an equation for ‘exhaustive’
    • In the pattern: Action2
      In an equation for ‘exhaustive’: exhaustive Action2 = ()
   |
32 |     exhaustive Action2 = ()
   |                ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Neat trick! Unless someone provides an answer using `TypeError`, I'll probably accept this as my closest to perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

`exhaustive` is handling a case that can never happen but that's not really an error. Or at least, it's working as intended for now, even if the type system could be improved to not allow handling of impossible cases.

Pattern-matching on `Action2` *provides* you the constraint `Member 'A '[ 'B, 'C ]` into your context. This is different from using `Action2` as an expression, which *requires* that constraint, and that would result in an error in the constraint solver.

Comment: How do you square this explanation with the observation that the compiler complains about not being able to prove `'False ~ 'True` when not using `TypeError`? If I were to read this answer literally, I would think that the compiler would then just introduce `'False ~ 'True` into the context, not produce an error.

Comment: @DanielWagner, the type checker *tries* to see if a pattern match is redundantly impossible; it doesn't always succeed.

Comment: @DanielWagner Indeed, I would expect that the constraint is not proved, but rather assumed by the type checker. GHC, in other cases, somehow decided that if the local assumptions are inconsistent then it must report an error -- in this case instead it does not. Perhaps inconsistency in the general case can not be decided, so GHC has to be imperfect? Sometimes I wish that GHC let me annotate such "impossible" cases, much like Agda `()` patterns.

Comment: @chi Ah, well, [that much at least you can do -- with some effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680830/how-can-i-use-contradictory-evidence). I previously wrote up an answer which did not give an error for `exhaustive` but did use `EmptyCase` to assert that the extra cases were impossible... but the trick I thought up in the meantime seemed strictly better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to go back to the first attempt:

```
type family MemberB (x :: k) (l :: [k]) where
  MemberB _ '[]      = 'False
  MemberB a (a : xs) = 'True
  MemberB a (b : xs) = MemberB a xs
```

But let's fix up `Member`.

```
type Member x l = Member' x l (MemberB x l)

type family Member' x l mem :: Constraint where
  Member' x l 'True = ()
  Member' x l 'False =
    TypeError ('ShowType x :<>:
               'Text " is not a member of " :<>:
               'ShowType l)
```

Comment: This still doesn't produce a type error for me. Does it for you?

Comment: @DanielWagner, no, it seems not to in this case. In some other contexts it should ....

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this answer while looking to resolve constraints as errors. After some fiddling I managed to encode a custom error as a constraint by using a type equality:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
import Data.Kind
import GHC.TypeLits

type family F a :: Constraint where
  F Foo = ()
  F t = () ~ TypeError ('Text "Type " :<>: 'ShowType t :<>: 'Text " is not supported.")

class C1 a where
  cc :: a -> a
  default cc :: F a => a -> a
  cc = id

data Foo
  deriving anyclass C1

data Bar
  deriving anyclass C1

main :: IO ()
main = pure ()
```

```
 /run/user/1000/tmp.53OJoiuM9m ghc -Wall -Wno-unused-top-binds foo.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( foo.hs, foo.o )

foo.hs:24:21: error:
    • Type Bar is not supported.
    • When deriving the instance for (C1 Bar)
   |
24 |   deriving anyclass C1
   |                     ^^
```